# AsyncDisplayKit CellNode setting highlighted color

Tags: ios, asyncdisplaykit

I'm using Async Display Kit to display cell nodes in an ASTableView. How can I set a custom color for the cell node's selected state. With normal tableView cells I would just override

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated

in my cell implementation, but that method doesn't exist on ASCellNodes. Has anyone else encountered this problem and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've subclassed ASCellNode to create your own cells, you could just add your own setHighlighted method.

e.g.

#### - In Your ASCellNode Subclass

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    if (highlighted) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    } else {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

#### - In Your Delegate Implementation

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyNodeSubclass * node = (MyNodeSubclass *)[(ASTableView *)tableView nodeForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];

    [node setHighlighted: YES];
}
```

Note:
You'll need to maintain your own state in regards to which cells are selected/deselected